# Rails 5 Routing Error - uninitialized constant DashboardController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I'm building out a multi-tenant site and am using Ryan Bigg's `https://leanpub.com/multi-tenancy-rails` as a guide.  I am stuck at creating a simple scoped route; I keep getting the error `Rails 5 Routing Error - uninitialized constant DashboardController`.  I am sure I am missing something simple as syntax has changed a bit since the final release of the publication.  Does my code below look as it should--right now I am just looking to get the dashboard index page to show?

**controllers/accounts/base_controller.rb**

```
 module Accounts
   class BaseController < ApplicationController
     before_action :authenticate_user!
   end
 end
```

**controllers/accounts/dashboard_controller.rb**

```
module Accounts
  class DashboardController < Accounts::BaseController
    def index
    end
  end
end
```

**views/accounts/dashboard/index.html.rb**

```
<section class="bg--secondary space--sm conversation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h1>Dashboard</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**routes.rb**

```
constraints(SubdomainRequired) do
  scope module: 'accounts' do
    root to: 'dashboard#index', as: :account_root
  end
end

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users

  constraints(SubdomainRequired) do
    root to: 'dashboard#index', as: :account_root
  end

  get '/accounts/new', to: 'accounts#new', as: :new_account
  post '/accounts', to: 'accounts#create', as: :accounts
  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

Comment: This might be just a mistake in the writeup of your question but you've got a syntax error in `base_controller.rb`. You're missing an `end` for the class definition of `BaseController`.

Comment: @SeanHuber yes, just a typo in post--fixed now

Answer (score 2):

I made multi tenant project soon and I had used lvh.me for development environment. Try the following solution:

**config/initializers/subdomain_constraint.rb**

```
class SubdomainConstraint
  def initialize
    @domain_development = 'lvh.me'
  end

  def matches?(request)
    if Rails.env.development?
      @domain_development == request.domain
    end
  end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
constraints(SubdomainConstraint.new) do
      match '', to: 'dashboard#index', constraints: {subdomain: /.+/}, via: [:get]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can define a class in the `routes.rb` file. Perhaps if you create a new file called `lib/subdomain_required.rb` and moved

```
class SubdomainRequired
  def self.matches?(request)
    request.subdomain.present? && request.subdomain != 'www'
  end
end
```

to that file instead of putting it in your `routes.rb`.

Comment: `routes.rb` is just another ruby script. There is no reason you can't define a class in it.

Comment: I think I've looked at this so much, I forgot something obvious.  I forgot to wrap `scope module: 'accounts' do` around my route.  Thank you for all your help.  @josh I did move my SubdomainRequired class to a separate file to keep my route file clean.